# sed: Replace all occurence of word X with Y only on line which contain word z

Tags: sed

I am trying to replace the word x with y after line 2 till the end only on lines where z is present using sed.

File:

```
X X X
X Y X
Z X X
X Y Z
```

Output:

```
Z Y Y
Y Y Z
```

Expected Output:

```
X X X
X Y X
Z Y Y
Y Y Z
```

I tried using

```
grep -i -e "Z" original.txt > copy.txt;
      sed -i '2,$ s/X/Y/g' files/copy.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
sed '5,$ { /Z/s/X/Y/g }' file > newfile
```

*Details*:

- `5,$` - defines the range of lines starting with Line 5 till end of file
- `{` - starting a command block

  - `/Z/` - find line with `Z`
  - `s/X/Y/g` - then, `s`ubstitute all (`g`) `X` with `Y`.
- `}` - end of the command block.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/CWUzWM):

```sh
#!/bin/bash
s='X X X
X Y X
X X X
X X X
Z X X
X Y Z'
sed '5,$ { /Z/s/X/Y/g }' <<< "$s"
# => X X X
#    X Y X
#    Z Y X
#    Y Y Z
```

Comment: Hi @Wiktor Stribiżew, this solved the problem but initially, I was using `sed -i 5,$ s/X/Y/g' file` but now I am getting If I try to `sed -i '5,$ /Z/X/Y/g' files > newfile`.

Comment: @SaadShamim Then `sed '5,$ { /Z/s/X/Y/g }' <<< "$s"` will work.

Comment: @SaadShamim Did it finally work?